# Javascript when button is clicked checks if the input matches a char in a random selected string and change the image to that letter

Tags: javascript

So I have my code so far producing the images and selecting a random word from an array list and producing the right number of images for characters in my random chosen word. My issue is that how do I check the exact input from a textbox when a button is clicked to see if the letter in the textbox is in the string and if so replace the correct image with the letter. If not have the letter show up to the side showing that is was already guessed.

```js
function change(){
  check();
}
function check(){
  var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var words = ["cat", "dog", "fish", "bird"];
  var select = words[num];
  var low = select.toLowerCase();
  alert(select);
  for(var b = 0; b < select.length; b++){
    var element = document.getElementById("main");
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/e/e5/Back-EN.png/revision/latest?cb=20100726082133");
    element.appendChild(img);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < low.length; i++){
    if(low.charAt(i) != low){
      var para = document.createElement("P");
      var node = document.createTextNode(a + " ");
      para.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById("main");
      element.appendChild(para);
    }
    else if(low.charAt(i) == low){
      var element = document.getElementById("main");
      img.setAttribute("src", "a");
      element.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body onload='change()'>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <div id="main">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Guess" id="input">
    <button onclick='clickCheck()'>Click</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I do not want any jquery.

Comment: first of all your method "clickCheck()" is not defined anywhere in your JS

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Please, update your question, it's not enough clear what you need and your code have a syntax problem that there's no function named `clickCheck()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using the Javascript then you can do it like this

```
<button id="abc" onClick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    //your code here to do what you want to
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
document.getElementById("#abc").addEventListener("click", function(){
//your code here
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: As said in your other answer: he wants when a click on the button, not keypress `"check the exact input from a textbox when a button is clicked"`

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can check it here @CalvinNunes

Comment: Yup you are right here. Sorry my bad I was caught up in between multiple answers

Comment: ok, I removed the downvote, but i'm not upvoting because what you are answering is exaclty what the OP already have, if you look his code, you will see that he is already using onclick (with errors, but is using), his question is about what to do after